# Product url with root-catalog and default-category

Tags: magento-1.9

Guys I am stuck with this issue, getting error like

> https://www.acom.pk/root-catalog/default-category/adata-hd710a-2tb.html ,

I don't want this `root-catalog` and `default-category` in my product url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change few settings at the backend:

Go to the Magento **Admin Panel**

```
System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Seo Options
```

Select yes or no from "Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs"

Refresh category url index
Option YES => http://www.example.com/category/subcategory.html

Option NO => http://www.example.com/subcategory.html

Comment: glad to help you, hope you can up vote the answer too :)